# How this <img>'s srcset computed out

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, srcset

I read an article about `srcset`: [Explaining The Last Clause of the src-n Grammar](http://www.xanthir.com/b4Su0). In this article, there is an example for explaining the complex of `srcset`.Here is part of it:

> It says that your layout has two breakpoints, at 640px and 960px, where your layout changes. In the smallest layout, this image will be presented at 100% of the viewport width, in the next it'll be 50% (a two-column design, perhaps), and in the largest it'll be 33% (a three-column design).

Next the author give the code demo of above condition expressed by using `srcset`:

```
<img srcset="
 320.jpg .89x 400w, 480.jpg 1.33x 400w, 640.jpg 1.78x 400w,
 480.jpg 1.04x 520w, 640.jpg 1.39x 520w, 960.jpg 2.09x 520w,
 640.jpg 1.1x 639w, 960.jpg 1.66x 639w, 1280 2.2x 639w,
 320.jpg 0.89x 800w, 480.jpg 1.33x 800w, 640.jpg 1.78x 800w,
 480.jpg 1.09x 959w, 640.jpg 1.45x 959w, 960.jpg 2.18x 959w,
 320.jpg 0.89x 1200w, 480.jpg 1.33x 1200w, 640.jpg 1.78x 1200w,
 480.jpg 1.09x 1440w, 640.jpg 1.45x 1440w, 960.jpg 2.18x 1440w,
 480.jpg 0.86x 1920w, 640.jpg 1.14x 1920w, 960.jpg 1.71x 1920w, 1280 2.29x 1920w,
 640.jpg 0.86x, 960.jpg 1.29x, 1280 1.71x, 1920 2.57x
">
```

However, I can't figure it out how the author computed all the stuff, which like the `.89`, `1.04`, `1.1`. How these pixel density computed out? In the description above there is only two breakpoints: `960px` and `640px`, so how the other `400w`, `520w`, `639w` comes out?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? This is not how srcset is standardized and implemented. This is only some old thoughts about it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't like idea of mixing 'x' with 'w'. Might even be a no-no, but can't say I've checked for sure.

I've been looking into srcset recently too. Lots of confusing & contradictory stuff out there. Nice & easy looking solution I've come up with which is very easy to implement and seems to fit the bill for me is shown below.
(Not sure if there are any problems with this approach, no doubt there will be, but don't know of any yet.)

Notes:

1) I just give the browser list of 21 possible images to use along with their widths.
2) the 'sizes' attribute has my CSS breakpoints at 537px, 639px etc with the actual size I want the image to display 300px, 350px etc. 
3) from simulations in Chrome either by zooming or changing pixel density from 1x to 2x, 4x, 8x it always chooses the best image for the job (e.g. a 480 'CSS px' wide display at 2x pixel density will choose the 640w image to fill the 300 'CSS px' image element.
4) couple of words of warning. Don't include any other image sizing elsewhere in your CSS or HTML.
5) not all browsers behave the same. Some either haven't implemented srcset yet or have only partially. I like to think Chrome have it right and the rest will follow suite.

```
          <img
            src="pictures/default.jpg"
            srcset="pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_80.jpg 80w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_95.jpg 95w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_113.jpg 113w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_134.jpg 134w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_160.jpg 160w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_190.jpg 190w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_226.jpg 226w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_269.jpg 269w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_320.jpg 320w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_381.jpg 381w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_453.jpg 453w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_538.jpg 538w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_640.jpg 640w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_761.jpg 761w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_905.jpg 905w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_1076.jpg 1076w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_1280.jpg 1280w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_1522.jpg 1522w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_1810.jpg 1810w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_2153.jpg 2153w,
                    pictures/Pic_a35_4_3_2560.jpg 2560w"
            sizes="(max-width: 537px) 300px,
                   (max-width: 639px) 350px,
                   (max-width: 759px) 400px,
                   (max-width: 904px) 450px,
                   (max-width: 1279px) 500px,
                   550px"
            alt="Pic_a35_4_3">
          </img>
```